# git push ошибка или как пушить origin/local_branch_name на сервер

Tags: git, git-branch

сделал

```
git branch local_branch_name origin/branch_name
```

после изменения пишу

```
git push origin/local_branch_name
```

ошибка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в чем ошибка? Как можно решить?

Comment: В вопросе одна команда, а на скриншоте другая. А ещё судя по промпту Git Bash вы в detached HEAD. И это плохо.

Comment: @D-side, и чё получается таким образом `git branch local_branch_name origin/branch_name` не хороший вариант для работы? Получается просто надо клонировать себе в master и пушить как origin, да?

Comment: `git branch local_branch_name origin/branch_name` - это создать ветку на базе другой, но **перейти в нее**!!!! нужно явно перейти с помощью checkout.

Comment: @KoVadim, и как в таком случае сделать `push`, никак?

Comment: для начала нужно привести коммиты в порядок, и тогда все получиться само собой. Я бы для начала выписал хеши коммитов (первых 6-7 знаков достаточно), потом переключился в мастер (git checkout master). А потом создал по нормальному ветку и черрипикнул туда коммиты. Расписывать детально?

Comment: Ой-ой. После правки текущий коммит-хэш на скриншоте изменился; вы ещё что-то закоммитили?

Comment: @D-side, два коммита еще добавлено

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Беда-а.

### `git branch` не переключает активную ветку!

Вы сделали ветку, но не переключились на неё, и коммит сделали не в неё.

В "ежедневном git-обиходе" вы почти не будете пользоваться `git branch` напрямую, скорее вы будете использовать `checkout` с опцией `-b` (от ***b***ranch):

```
git checkout -b новая-ветка
```

...что сделает ветку там же, где вы (`HEAD`) **сейчас**, а также **переключится** на неё. Если вы хотите ветку в каком-то другом месте, то его и укажите:

```
git checkout -b новая-ветка место-новой-ветки
```

### Не трогайте remote-ветки (каковыми являются `origin/*`)!

**Единственное**, для чего они нужны, это для индикации вам, где находятся ветки сервера. Даже при взаимодействии с сервером вы эти ветки указывать не будете, поскольку для сервера их не существует. И коммитить в них не принято. Общий вид `git-push` такой:

```
git push <сервер> <откуда-локально>:<куда-на-сервере>
```

Плюс сокращённые формы:

```
git push <сервер> <откуда-локально> # зальётся в ветку "за которой следит"
git push # как выше, но текущая ветка
```

### Что делать?

Я полагаю, события развивались следующим образом:

```
git checkout origin/DIMA # это уже крайне подозрительное действие
git branch DIMA origin/DIMA # создали ветку, но не переключились
git commit ... # что-то закоммитили: ой, вы же были в detached HEAD вне веток!
git commit ... # ещё что-то закоммитили!
```

...и если я приблизительно прав, то проблема решится просто мёрджем "коммитов-потеряшек" (*англ.* **dangling commits**) в ветку, куда они предназначались изначально; если ветка сейчас точно позади них (и не ушла с тех пор вперёд), то произойдёт **fast-forward**. Поэтому добавим в мердж флаг `--ff-only`, чтобы если я неправ (и вы сломали репозиторий сильнее, чем я думал), мерджа не произошло.

Сначала зафиксируем "потеряшек", обозначив им стабильное место в истории.
**"В любой непонятной ситуации делай ветку"**

```
git checkout -b marker
```

Теперь надо идти туда, куда эти коммиты предназначались.

```
git checkout DIMA
```

А теперь попробуем перемотать `DIMA` вперёд, включив в него бывших "потеряшек":

```
git merge --ff-only marker
```

...и если мердж произошёл, то, похоже, я угадал ваш сценарий, и выглядит он, с моими манипуляциями (после первой команды => после третьей), примерно так:

[image: схема коммитов]

И теперь, по идее, можно сделать просто `git push` (без всего) и ветка уйдёт на сервер.

---

#### Что за "потеряшки"?

Это коммиты, до которых нельзя добраться от "зафиксированных точек", следуя "назад" (по ссылкам на родительские коммиты). Такими "зафиксированными точками" являются **ветки** (branch) и **метки** (tag).

Все коммиты, до которых Git не может дойти от таких точек, являются мусором и подлежат удалению *когда-нибудь*, гарантировать их сохранность уже нельзя, их в любой момент может съесть `git gc`. Отсюда и "потеряшки", для истории эти коммиты потеряны, если кто-то (например, `git reflog`) не записал их хэш.

Такие коммиты порождает, например, `git commit --amend`, или любой содержательный (не fast-forward) `git rebase`.

Comment: Десять коммитов-потеряшек из десяти! Отличный ответ )

Comment: о, а меня дима как раз зовут. плюсану