# проблема с git detached head

Tags: git

после checkout HEAD^2(стоя на хэде), head становится detached. после этого комитить нельзя. Почему создатели гита запретили такой комит ? что он нарушает в сущности ?

Comment: @D-side checkout HEAD^2 например , когда находишься на хэде

Comment: (См. также) [Потому что легко прострелить себе ногу.](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/505069/181100)

Comment: *Почему создатели гита запретили такой комит ?* — а почему вы решили, что запретили? попробовал воссоздать ситуацию — спокойно добавился коммит к detached head-у. версия *git* — 1.7.10.4 // опишите, пожалуйста, подробнее, в чём именно у вас проблема.

Comment: ...и выше по ссылке, собстна, пример того, что бывает, если сделать в detached HEAD пару коммитов, так что это ещё как реально :)