# Что такое remotes/origin/HEAD?

Tags: git

Вот при вызове команды `git branch -a` получаю такой вывод

```
aleksey@aleksey:~/Downloads/NTZ/FittingRoom$ git branch -a
develop
* master
remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
remotes/origin/master
```

Ветка `develop` и `master` понятно, что это 2 мои локальные ветки, но понятно, что такое

```
remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
remotes/origin/master
```

Это удаленные ветки, но в чем их отличия и почему одна `HEAD` ... Я так понял, что `head` это та ветка в которую я делаю пуш, но так это должна быть `master`...

Я так понимаю, что это должно выглядеть так

```
aleksey@aleksey:~/Downloads/NTZ/FittingRoom$ git branch -a
develop
* master
remotes/origin/master
```

2 ветки локальные и одна `master` удаленная...

Зачем `head`?

ПРАВКА. Добавил еще ветку `origin/develop` и после выполнения команды `git checkout origin/develop` получаю вот такой вывод через `git branch -a`

```
aleksey@aleksey:~/Downloads/NTZ/FittingRoom$ git branch -a
* (detached from origin/develop)
develop
master
remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
remotes/origin/develop
remotes/origin/master
```

Я так понял, что `HEAD` может указывать только на ветки удаленного репазитория... Но почему тогда после переключения на удаленную ветку дев стока `HEAD` все равно указывает на мастер??

```
remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
```

Вот согласно статье на хабре

> текущее состояние не изменённых файлов, находящихся под контролем версий, есть тот коммит, на который указывает HEAD

ниче не понятно, `HEAD` в итоге указывает на ту ветку где ты находится или на ветку в которую ты сделал последний коммит?

Comment: head - это указатель на текущее состояние. См. https://habrahabr.ru/post/157175/

Comment: зачем вы постоянно ставите метки github и gitlab?

Comment: @Etki ну мне так показалось как будто этот вопрос относится к ним...

Comment: gitlab и github - всего лишь хранилища, никак не изменяющие интерфейс гита.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

ветка (*branch*) в *git* — это (плавающий) указатель на *commit*.

`HEAD`/`.git/HEAD` (технически) — это файл, содержащий указатель либо на текущую (для репозитория) ветку (например, файл может содержать такой текст `ref: refs/heads/master`), либо на текущий *commit* (т.н. *detached head*, файл содержит строку с хэш-суммой этого *commit-а*).

удалённый репозиторий ничем не «хуже» вашего локального, и в нём тоже есть такой файл, и информация, выдаваемая командой `branch`:

```
remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
```

сообщает вам о том, что этот файл в удалённом репозитории [в момент клонирования](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12613793/4827341) содержал ссылку на ветку `master` (в том же, удалённом репозитории).

---

> Я так понял, что head это та ветка в которую я делаю пуш

*push* вы делаете в ту ветку, которую сами и указали. либо явно, например так:

```
$ git push репозиторий ветка
```

либо неявно, «привязав» вашу локальную ветку к (произвольной) ветке в удалённом репозитории, и вызывая `git push` без дополнительных параметров.

посмотреть «привязки» веток можно, например, командой `remote show репозиторий`:

```
$ git remote show origin
...
  Local branch configured for 'git pull':
    master merges with remote master
  Local ref configured for 'git push':
    master pushes to master (up to date)
```

---

### по поводу дополнения к вопросу

во-первых, я уже ответил практически на тот же вопрос: [Почему получаю detached head?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/543892/178576).

во-вторых, вынесу (и дополню) сюда основное:

1. эта строка (`remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master`) в выдаче команды `branch` появляется благодаря наличию в вашем локальном хранилище файла `refs/remotes/origin/HEAD`, содержащего в вашем случае:

   ```
   $ cat .git/refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
   ref: refs/remotes/origin/master
   ```

   вы можете абсолютно безболезненно удалить этот файл. тогда эта строчка пропадёт из вывода команды `branch`.

   файл этот был создан во время клонирования и содержит информацию о том, какая именно ветка была распакована при этом в ваш *рабочий каталог*.
2. вероятно, вы спутали этот файл (`.git/refs/remotes/origin/HEAD`) с файлом `.git/HEAD`, который как раз и содержит ссылку на вашу текущую ветку (или на коммит, если ваше хранилище находится в «состоянии *detached head*»).
3. > Я так понял, что `HEAD` может указывать только на ветки удаленного репазитория.

   нет. файл `.git/HEAD` может хранить:

   - либо указатель на локальную ветку (т.е., содержать что-то вроде `ref: refs/heads/master`)
   - либо хэш коммита (т.н. «состояние *detached head*»)
4. > Но почему тогда после переключения на удаленную ветку дев стока HEAD все равно указывает на мастер?
   >
   > ```
   > remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
   > ```

   ещё раз повторяю: эта строка в выводе команды `branch` появляется лишь по одной причине — из-за наличия файла `.git/refs/remotes/origin/HEAD`. этот файл **ни на что** не влияет. вы его можете абсолютно безболезненно удалить. и тогда этой строки уже не будет в выводе команды `branch`.
5. > Вот согласно статье на хабре
   >
   > > текущее состояние не изменённых файлов, находящихся под контролем версий, есть тот коммит, на который указывает HEAD
   >
   > ниче не понятно, HEAD в итоге указывает на ту ветку где ты находится или на ветку в которую ты сделал последний коммит?

   последний коммит здесь абсолютно ни при чём.

   - если файл `.git/HEAD` содержит указатель на локальную ветку (т.е., содержит что-то вроде `ref: refs/heads/master`), то, значит, у вас в *рабочем каталоге* распакован коммит, на который указывает локальная ветка `master`. хэш этого коммита хранится в файле `.git/refs/heads/master`
   - если же файл `.git/HEAD` содержит хэш коммита (т.н. «состояние *detached head*»), то именно этот коммит сейчас и распакован в вашем *рабочем каталоге*.

Comment: Я вот такой ветки у себя ни разу не видел... Может ли вопрос автора быть связан с тем, что его удаленный репозиторий имеет рабочую копию (не является *bare*)?

Comment: Кроме того, не понятно почему HEAD удаленного репозитория вообще оказалась вытянута. Я почему-то всегда думал, что "вытягиваются" только `refs/heads/*`, а HEAD под этот шаблон не попадает же.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, *Может ли вопрос автора быть связан с тем, что его удаленный репозиторий имеет рабочую копию (не является bare)?* — скорее всего, так и есть. по крайней мере у меня в тестах такая строка в выдаче `branch -r` присутствует только в такой ситуации.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, *"вытягиваются" только refs/heads/\** — «вытягивается» то, что указано в директиве *fetch* в файле *config*. по умолчанию это `+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`. вот в `refs/remotes/origin` и попадает файл `HEAD`. и, насколько вижу, он не изменяется и остаётся таким же, каким создан при клонировании.

Comment: Вот именно, по умолчанию там `+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`. Разве HEAD лежит в `refs/heads/`? Оно же лежит в корне...

Comment: @PavelMayorov, нет, неправду я выше написал. при клонировании **непустого** bare-репозитрия такой файл создайтся тоже.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, *Разве HEAD лежит в refs/heads/? Оно же лежит в корне* — ну, так происходит при клонировании. а потом содержимое `.git/refs/remotes/*/HEAD`, насколько вижу, уже не изменяется, несмотря на изменения `HEAD` в удалённом репозитории.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, http://stackoverflow.com/q/12613793/4827341

Comment: В момент клонирования или последнего fetch? Мне кажется, что второе.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, тестирование показывает, что файл `refs/remotes/origin/HEAD` создаётся только при клонировании непустого репозитория. по-другому получить его не получилось.

Answer (score 5):

`head` это то состояния версии в которой вы в данный момент находитесь. 
это значит, если вы переключились на другую ветку и у вас хед позади других коммитов, значит вам нужно сделать `pull`, чтобы получить свежую версию этой ветки.

И для переключения между ветками лучше использовать `git checkout <branch>`, а для просмотра удаленных веток `git remote`.

Answer (score 5):

```
remotes/origin/master
```

Это ветка, предназначенная "только для чтения". Её положение обозначает последнее известное (после последнего `push`/`pull`/`fetch`) положение ветки `master` на сервере `origin`.

```
remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
```

`HEAD` в Git это "текущая верхушка". Локальный `HEAD` обычно показывает место на графе коммитов, в котором **сейчас** находится рабочее дерево<sup>[0]</sup> (например, сделан `checkout`).

***Но здесь другой случай.*** это **не просто `HEAD`, а из `origin`**. Как и все remote-ветки, предназначен **только для чтения**, но на что он указывает?

На практике `origin/HEAD` обычно указывает **ветку по умолчанию** для удалённого репозитория. Практических последствий у этого почти никаких, разве что при клонировании репозитория локальный `HEAD` будет там же, где на момент клонирования был `HEAD` на сервере. Когда вы работаете у себя на машине, `origin/HEAD` вам не нужен.

Ситуация становится чуть интереснее, когда к удалённому репозиторию есть интерфейс доступа. Для него `HEAD` может означать что-то ещё. Например, на GitHub `origin/HEAD` или, как у них называется, **default branch** можно выбрать в настройках, и прочитать пояснение о том, для чего это надо:

> The default branch is considered the “base” branch in your repository, against which all pull requests and code commits are automatically made, unless you specify a different branch.
>
> ("Ветка по умолчанию считается "основной" веткой в вашем репозитории, в которую делаются все pull-request'ы и коммиты, если не выбирать другую ветку явно." *прим. пер.*)

---

**Почему `origin/*` только для чтения?** Эти ветки являются "отражением"<sup>[1]</sup> того, что есть на сервере `origin`. Поэтому эти ветки меняются только тогда, когда ваши действия меняют репозиторий в `origin`. Скажем, в процессе `push` Git передаёт серверу коммиты, дожидается его подтверждения о получении и сдвигает "отражение" на новую точку. Любые изменения в обход этого механизма рискуют сломать саму суть `origin/*` как отражений.

Если переместиться в ветку-отражение (посредством `checkout`), Git заметит, что её нельзя<sup>[2]</sup> менять, поэтому `HEAD` перейдёт **не в ветку**, а на коммит, на котором она находится, **отделившись от веток** (отсюда `detached HEAD`). [И с этого момента надо быть осторожным.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/505069/181100)

---

> текущее состояние не изменённых файлов, находящихся под контролем версий, есть тот коммит, на который указывает HEAD

Надеюсь, из текста выше понятно, что у вас есть `HEAD` (ваш) и `origin/HEAD` (удалённый). В статье о первом. А в списке веток есть только последний.

---

<sup>[0]</sup> *на самом деле скорее наоборот, рабочее дерево само по себе, а `HEAD` нужен, чтобы вычислить и записать внесённые изменения, это "отправная точка"*
<sup>[1]</sup> *этот термин честно выдуман мной, употребляйте осторожно*
<sup>[2]</sup> *можно всё, но многие вещи ломают настолько много, что оно того не стоит*

Comment: Отражение — отличный термин. Уж куда лучше «удалённых веток».

Answer (score 1):

HEAD - это текущая ветка. Например, Ваша ветка называется Aleksey_Timoshchenko, и чтобы не писать это длинное название, можете, находясь в ней, писать HEAD:

`git push origin HEAD`

Эта строчка добавит изменения в текущую ветку.

Comment: Это только про локальный `HEAD`. В вопросе же фигурирует `HEAD` с сервера, это совсем другая штука.

Comment: То есть серверный HEAD - это указатель на "главную" ветку на сервере?

Comment: Да, верно. Эта ветка, например, будет в рабочем дереве после клонирования репозитория. Других применений пока не найдено (во всяком случае, мной).