# Почему получаю detached head?

Tags: git, git-checkout

Команда `git branch -a` выводит вот такое

```
aleksey@aleksey:~/Downloads/NTZ/FittingRoom$ git branch -a
* develop
master
remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
remotes/origin/develop
remotes/origin/master
```

после того как переключаюсь на ветку `develop` в репазитории `origin`:

```
$ git checkout origin/develop
```

получаю вот такой вывод через `git branch -a`

```
aleksey@aleksey:~/Downloads/NTZ/FittingRoom$ git branch -a
* (detached from origin/develop)
develop
master
remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
remotes/origin/develop
remotes/origin/master
```

Так вот я тут почитал, что состояние `detached` получаем вот так

> Оно характеризуется тем, что HEAD указывает не на вершину ветки, а просто на коммит. HEAD всегда должен указывать только на вершину какой-либо ветки!

Почему тогда я получаю `detached` если это моя ветка?? Это ж не просто коммит...

ПРАВКА

При переключении на удаленную ветку `develop` получаю такое сообщение

```
aleksey@aleksey:~/Downloads/NTZ/FittingRoom$ git checkout    origin/develop 
Note: checking out 'origin/develop'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again.   Example:

git checkout -b new_branch_name

HEAD is now at ee16cd4... service
```

Comment: origin/develop - это не ваша ветка

Comment: @Etki а чья? Тут кроме меня никого нет...

Comment: удаленного репозитория, очевидно.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

1. > HEAD всегда должен указывать только на вершину какой-либо ветки!

   Ветка в *git* — это плавающий указатель на коммит. у указателя нет и не может быть никакой «вершины».

   Специальный указатель `HEAD` вполне может указывать и не на ветку, а на конкретный коммит (т.н. *detached head*). как в вашем случае.

   Это просто «нестандартная» ситуация, которая может понадобиться в особых случаях.
2. > Почему тогда я получаю detached если это моя ветка?

   `origin/develop` — это ветка **не** из вашего локального хранилища. Насколько я понимаю из предыдущих ваших вопросов, к этой ветке «привязана» ваша локальная ветка `develop`. После полной синхронизации между ними (`git pull`+`git push`) обе они будут указывать на один и тот же коммит, и, следовательно, распакованные из этого коммита деревья файлов/каталогов будут полностью идентичны.

Потому вам, скорее всего, требуется

```
$ git checkout develop
```

а не

```
$ git checkout origin/develop
```

---

### Ответы на дополнительные вопросы, заданные в комментарии:

> 1) Если я хочу переключиться на удаленную ветку `develop`, то почему я получаю сообщение про `detached head`?

Краткий ответ: потому что так задумано.

Более длинный ответ требует захода очень издалека. Попробую.

Как вы (надеюсь) знаете из толстых руководств, каждый коммит содержит в себе привязку к другому, *родительскому* коммиту (есть два исключения: самый первый в хранилище коммит не имеет такой привязки, а т.н. *коммиты слияния* (*merge commits*) могут содержать два и более *родительских коммита*). Посмотреть эту информацию можно, например, так:

```
$ git cat-file -p хэш-коммита
...
parent хэше-родительского-коммита
...
```

Как программа *git* «узнаёт», что туда подставить (при вызове `git commit`)? Она черпает информацию из файла `HEAD` в корне хранилища (`.git/HEAD`).

Если этот файл содержит хэш коммита (т.н. «состояние *detached head*), то этот коммит и есть *родительский*.

А если этот файл содержит ссылку на ветку («нормальное состояние») — `ref: refs/heads/ветка` — то хэш *родительского коммита* берётся из соответствующего файла — `.git/refs/heads/ветка`.

Саму процедуру создания коммита (её «технический» аспект) я описывать не буду («на полях слишком мало места» © пьер ферма), но упомяну про действие в финале этого процесса:

Если файл `HEAD` содержит хэш коммита («состояние *detached head*), то в этот файл записывается новое содержимое — хэш только что созданного коммита.

А если этот файл содержит ссылку на ветку («нормальное состояние»), то хэш вновь полученного коммита записывается в файл, на который указывает эта ссылка — `.git/refs/heads/ветка`. вот так и реализуется механизм «плавающего указателя на коммит» (которым и является ветка в *git*).

Возвращаемся к вопросу. Содержимое файла `HEAD` изменяется командой `checkout`. Так почему же, если мы укажем команде локальную ветку, она запишет в этот файл `ref: refs/heads/ветка`, а если укажем ветку удалённого хранилища, то она запишет в файл хэш коммита, на который указывает эта ветка (создав «состояние *detached head*), вместо, например `ref: refs/remotes/хранилище/ветка`?

А давайте посмотрим, что выйдет в таком случае.

Запишем руками в файл `.git/HEAD`, например, `ref: refs/remotes/origin/master`, внесём изменение в какой-нибудь файл в *рабочем каталоге* и сделаем *git commit*.

Хэш этого коммита будет вписан в указанный нами файл — `.git/refs/remotes/origin/master`. Вроде бы (пока) всё в порядке.

**Но**. если мы выполним команду `fetch` (действия, выполняемые ею, совершаются и в начале исполнения команды `pull`), то содержимое файла `.git/refs/remotes/origin/master` будет перезаписано информацией из удалённого хранилища! И наш новый коммит «сгинет» где-то в недрах нашего локального хранилища: на него не будет ссылок ни с помощью веток, ни с помощью меток (*tags* — это тоже указатели на коммит, но, в отличие от веток, «фиксированные», а не «плавающие»), ни с помощью строки `parent хэш` в каком-либо другом коммите. Да, конечно, этот бесхозный коммит можно будет посмотреть, помня его хэш, но и только.

Вот (в частности) чтобы не создавать такой «бардак», `checkout` и не запишет в файл `HEAD` ссылку на удалённую ветку.

Другая причина (по-моему, более веская) — неопределённость действий *git* при командах `pull`/`push` в нашей искусственно созданной ситуации. Да, в текущей реализации *git* откажется что-либо делать, выдав по простыне сообщений об ошибках. Но если реализовывать какое-то поведение в такой ситуации, то каким оно должно быть? Я лично затрудняюсь с ответом. Вполне вероятно, что и у разработчиков программы такая же проблема. Вот при `git checkout удалённая-ветка` они и решили записывать в `HEAD` хэш коммита (создавая «состояние *detached head*»), а не ссылку на удалённую ветку (создавая неопределённость).

> 2) Я перешел на локальную `develop`, сделал пуш в удаленный `develop`, потом сделал пул, и все равно когда переключаюсь на удаленый `develop`, он пишет `detached from origin/develop` - это нормально или нет?

Да, это нормально. см. выше.

> 3) Почему куда бы я не переключался, мой хед всегда стоит на месте `remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master`?

Эта строка в выдаче команды `branch` появляется благодаря наличию в хранилище файла `refs/remotes/origin/HEAD`, содержащего в вашем случае:

```
$ cat .git/refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
ref: refs/remotes/origin/master
```

Вы можете абсолютно безболезненно удалить этот файл. тогда эта строчка пропадёт из вывода команды `branch`.

Файл этот был создан во время клонирования и содержит информацию о том, какая именно ветка была распакована при этом в ваш *рабочий каталог*. Если бы вы клонировали с опцией `--bare` (`git clone --bare url-хранилища`), то этот файл не был бы создан (как и *рабочий каталог* с распакованными из хранилища файлами).

«Ваш» же файл `HEAD`, находится непосредственно в корне хранилища: `.git/HEAD`.

Comment: Вроде понятно и вроде не до конца) Но можете мне тогда еще раз подсказать. 1) Если я хочу переключиться на удаленную ветку дев то почему я получаю сообщение(добавил в вопрос) 2) Я перешел на локальную дев сделал пуш в удаленный дев,  потом сделал пул и все равно когда переключаюсь на удаленый дев он пишет `detached from origin/develop` - это норм или нет? 3) Почему куда бы я не переключался мой хед всегда стоит на месте `remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master`?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, я дополнил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо за такой подробный ответ) Только теперь нужно еще пару раз прочитать и нарисовать на листочке))