# Как откатить commit в git?

Tags: git

Откатываю коммит так:

```
git checkout  2f3bd1b
```

Как теперь отправить его в `master`?

Comment: `git push -f` кажется так

Comment: посмотри git help push, но вообще тебе -f (перезаписывает просто)

Answer (score 4):

обычно под термином «откатить коммит» подразумевают перестановку указателя («ветки» в терминологии *git*)) на более старый коммит.

а командой *checkout* с указанием хэша коммита вы лишь изменяете содержимое рабочей копии. и получаете [состояние «detached head»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/543838/178576), вернуться из которого можно той же командой *checkout*, передав параметром имя нужного указателя (вероятно, `master`).

для перестановки **текущего** указателя (и изменения рабочей копии) [можно воспользоваться](https://githowto.com/ru/removing_commits_from_a_branch) такой, например, командой (предупреждение: все изменения в отслеживаемых файлах и содержимое индекса будут утеряны):

```
$ git reset --hard хэш-нужного-коммита
```

---

а для отправки этого значения указателя в другое хранилище (в случае если этот указатель там указывает на более новый коммит) надо добавить команде *push* опцию `-f` (`--force`). но будьте готовы к [подводным камням](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/572907/178576).

Comment: Вы б предупредили об опасностях --hard ресета.

Comment: @AK, я думаю, в данной ситуации эти опасности вряд ли существенны. но, впрочем, предупреждение добавил.