# Как правильно откатить merge в git

Tags: git

Последовательность моих действий:

```
git branch test1; 
git checkout test1;
<<Внес изменения>>
git add . ;
git commit -m "тестовый коммит";
git checkout master;
git merge test1;
git push;
```

Ситуация в том, что мне нужно было смержить методом слияния git merge test1 --no-ff, а у меня получилось перемоткой.

Как правильно откатить или перемержить этот мерж, чтобы убрать перемотку и увидеть ветки в графе со всеми коммитами в ветке test1? Желательно чтобы в истории этого косячка не осталось..

Comment: Точно так же, как и любой другой коммит https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/890837

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вернуться (reset) на коммит, который был в ветке master до merge
смёржить правильно
запушить через force

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard HEAD~
git merge test1 --no-ff
git -f push
```