# Куда пропадают commit-ы после перехода к состоянию

Tags: git, git-commit, git-checkout, git-log

Создаю репозитарий с коммитами

```bsh
git init
touch 1.txt
touch 2.txt
git add .
git commit -m "POINT 1"
touch 3.txt 
git add .
git commit -m "POINT 2"
```

на данном этапе имеем репозитарий с двумя коммитами, которые можно увидеть в листинге с помощью `git log` и далее переходим к коммиту `POINT 1` командой `git checkout d5b633`

в результате переходим к состоянию коммита `POINT 1` и видим, что из листинга `git log` пропал `POINT 2`, однако его можно обнаружить вызвав другой список (листинг) с помощью `git reflog` вывожу список:

```bsh
$ git reflog
d5b633b (HEAD) HEAD@{0}: checkout: moving from master to d5b6
ab5ba15 (master) HEAD@{1}: commit: POINT 2
d5b633b (HEAD) HEAD@{2}: commit (initial): POINT 1
```

Вижу пропавший коммит  `POINT 2` и ввожу его хеш с командой:

```bsh
git checkout ab5b
```

Команда работает. Файловая система приходит в соответствие состоянию коммита `POINT 2`
Объяснить пожалуйста, почему после вышеуказанных действий пропадают из листингов коммиты, как `git log`, а команда `git status` возвращает сообщение

```bsh
HEAD detached at ab5ba15
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

???

P.S. никак не мог поставить к данному сообщению тэг «GIT» (нет в списке)

Comment: [вопрос — на самом деле — про то же самое](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/543838/178576)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При выполнении команды `checkout` вы передвигаете указатель `HEAD` на ветку (ветка - это по факту ее верхний коммит и все те, по которым можно перейти вглубь, у каждого коммита есть ссылка на предыдущий, все вместе выглядит похоже на структуру данных список). После того как вы передвинули указатель `HEAD`, коммит `point 2` получился как бы над этой веткой, то есть вне ее, поэтому его нет в выводе команды `git log`, у которой есть много опций, и если ввести команду с опцией `--all`, то коммит вы увидите (я пользуюсь командой `git log --all --graph --oneline` если надо увидеть, то чего обычно не видно, она выводит и сташи (`stash`), которые тоже представляют из себя временные коммиты).

И ваши изменения остались во втором коммите, следовательно изменений ни в файловой системе, ни в индексе нет, поэтому вывод команды `git status` - нечего коммитить.
Команда которая не просто передвигает `HEAD`, а еще и изменяет и коммиты, и индекс, и файловую систему - `git reset` (`--soft` или `--hard` или без параметров), сделав ее на `HEAD^` вы как раз увидите изменения в `git status`.

Comment: Только не список, а дерево, точнее говоря направленный граф. Весь Git — это исслюстрация работы теории графов.