# Обратная связь между директорией .git и рабочей директорией

Tags: git

Правильно ли я представляю себе процесс взаимодействия между рабочей папкой проекта и папкой .git?

После создания папки .git она хранит в себе информацию о коммитах. Перемещая указатель HEAD, можно указывать нужный этап разработки приложения, а вернее, те изменения, которые были произведены в нем с момента самого первого коммита.

Но меня сейчас интересует не эта, а рабочая папка. Допустим, у меня есть последний, устраивающий меня коммит, после которого были сделаны определенные изменения, созданы новые папки и файлы. Эти изменения я еще не коммитил, но пришел к выводу о том, что все что было создано на данном этапе есть полная ерунда.

Могу ли я вернуть состояние своей рабочей папке к тому, при котором был создан последний коммит без сохранения вновь созданных файлов и папок и каких либо изменений в файлах проекта?

Я надеялся получить такой результат используя команду:

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

, но он никаким образом не повлиял на состояние рабочей папки. Похоже, я не понимаю самой сути работы с системой версионного контроля, поскольку почти никогда ею не пользовался.

Answer (score 2):

каталог `.git` — это и есть само хранилище (другое название — «репозиторий»). там хранится вся история изменений.

ветка (*branch*) и метка (*tag*) — это два типа указателей на коммит. ветка — «плавающий» (автоматически переключается после каждой команды `commit`), метка — фиксированный.

`HEAD` — это специальный мета-указатель, подсказывающий вам и программе *git*, из какого именно указателя в данный момент извлечены файлы/каталоги в рабочем каталоге (`HEAD` может указывать и непосредственно на коммит — это [особое состояние «detached head»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/543838/178576)).

программа *git* использует значение `HEAD`, например, для вычисления, какие именно файлы были изменены/добавлены/удалены пользователем в дереве рабочего каталога.

переопределять самостоятельно значение `HEAD` (хранится в файле `.git/HEAD`) ни в коем случае не стоит — так вы введёте в заблуждение программу *git*. она сама изменяет это значение при необходимости — в процессе выполнения некоторых команд (например: `checkout`, `reset`, `commit`).

---

> Вот у меня есть история коммитов: A->B->C->D->E->F. Я хочу привести свою рабочую папку в то состояние в котором делался коммит E (т.е. все папки и файлы в том виде, в котором они были на тот момент).

просто привести состояние рабочего каталога к определённому коммиту можно командой `checkout`:

```
$ git checkout хэш.коммита
```

при этом вы получите [состояние «detached head»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/543838/178576).

а чтобы после этого переставить на данный коммит указатель типа «ветка» (к примеру — `master`), вам сначала надо переключиться на этот указатель (сделать его «текущим»):

```
$ git checkout master
```

и затем воспользоваться командой `reset`:

```
$ git reset --hard хэш.коммита
```

Answer (score 2):

Вы всё правильно описали за одним исключением

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

не удаляет файлы и папки, которые не были добавлены в репозиторий. Для их удаления нужна команда

```
git clean -d
```

Параметр `-d` указывает, что папки тоже нужно удалять.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы хотите полностью безвозвратно убрать все изменения, сделанные после коммита `1234abcd`, то верная команда:

```sh
$ git reset --hard "1234abcd"
```

Будьте с ней осторожны, так как отменить это действие нельзя.

---

Если же вы хотите привести файлы в состояние этих же файлов в другой ветке или другом коммите, то вам нужен `checkout`:

```sh
$ git checkout "1234abcd" -- .
```

Comment: Спасибо, но все эти команды касаются истории коммитов. Я же хочу привести в исходное состояние рабочую папку. Чтобы исходной точке, на которую указывает HEAD (в указанном примере это коммит "1234abcd") находилась рабочая папка проекта. Именно так я себе представлял работу системы контроля версий. Но, похоже, я ее совсем неправильно представлял. Вот и результат Вашей команды говорит о том, что HEAD is now at 29d7988 The very first commit. И что мне с этого? Папка .git живет своей жизнью, рабочая - своей, удаленный репозиторий - своей. Как это все связать воедино?

Comment: У вас странные вопросы. Удалённый репозиторий живёт своей жизнью, потому что git является _распределённой_ системой контроля версий. Папка `.git` вас вообще не должна интересовать.

Comment: На самом деле вопрос очень простой: я хочу понять суть работы системы контроля версий git. А именно, как располагая данной системой, получать эти самые версии? Т.е. ради чего все задумывалось. Вот у меня есть история коммитов: A->B->C->D->E->F. Я хочу привести свою рабочую папку в то состояние в котором делался коммит E (т.е. все папки и файлы в том виде, в котором они были на тот момент). Ну или получить это состояние в каком-либо другом месте.

Comment: @vitaliy4us См. правку. Если и это не то, что вам нужно, то я уже не знаю.

Comment: Стоит упомянуть разницу между анонимным бранчем (когда checkout сделан по hash) и именованым (`git checkout -b <new branch> <HASH>`).