# Переключится на ветку Git

Tags: git, github, git-branch

```
    C:\Work\prohabits-ui-html2>git remote show origin
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: ----(ссылка удалена)
  Push  URL: ----(ссылка удалена)
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branches:
    feature/admin-settings-teams                      new (next fetch will store in remotes/origin)
    master                                            tracked
    refs/remotes/origin/feature/admin-users           stale (use 'git remote prune' to remove)
    refs/remotes/origin/feature/super-admin-protracks stale (use 'git remote prune' to remove)
    refs/remotes/origin/feature/super-admin-users     stale (use 'git remote prune' to remove)
    refs/remotes/origin/super-admin-protracks         stale (use 'git remote prune' to remove)
    staging                                           tracked
  Local branches configured for 'git pull':
    feature/super-admin-protracks  merges with remote super-admin-protracks
    feature/super-admin-protracks1 merges with remote feature/super-admin-protracks
    master                         merges with remote super-admin-protracks
    super-admin-protracks          merges with remote super-admin-protracks
  Local ref configured for 'git push':
    master pushes to master (local out of date)
```

Мне нужно переключится на удаленную ветку `feature/admin-settings-teams.`
Пробовал по разному. Что я делаю не так?

```
C:\Work\prohabits-ui-html2>git checkout feature/admin-settings-teams
error: pathspec 'feature/admin-settings-teams' did not match any file(s) known to git.

C:\Work\prohabits-ui-html2>git checkout feature
error: pathspec 'feature' did not match any file(s) known to git.

C:\Work\prohabits-ui-html2>git checkout admin-settings-teams
error: pathspec 'admin-settings-teams' did not match any file(s) known to git.

C:\Work\prohabits-ui-html2>git checkout admin-settings-teams
error: pathspec 'admin-settings-teams' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я полагаю, вы не хотите переключиться на удалённую ветку **напрямую***, потому что это означает переход в detached HEAD и [может привести к приключениям](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/505118/181100). А скорее вы хотите завести локальную ветку, соответствующую этой удалённой. Тонкость скорее терминологическая, но опасная.

---

**Читайте внимательнее.** Git вам даже рассказывает, как это сделать:

```
  Remote branches:
    feature/admin-settings-teams            new (next fetch will store in remotes/origin)
                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Что как бы намекает вам, что нужно сделать `git fetch`.
*(или `git fetch origin`, в сложных случаях)*

А дальше как обычно:

```
git checkout feature/admin-settings-teams
```

---

* Но если очень хотите, то `git fetch` и `git checkout origin/feature/admin-settings-teams`.

Answer (score 1):

Вы пытаетесь переключиться локально на ветку, а этой ветки у вас не существует, скопируйте себе удаленные ветки, которые вам нужны.

```
git clone http://whatever.git -b branch-name
```

Comment: Существование веток типа `refs/remotes/origin/...` подразумевает, что локальный репозиторий уже связан с удаленным и был `git clone` и/или `git fetch`. В уже существующем репозитории `git clone` не сработает, а новый создавать просто незачем.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте обновить информацию о ветках в удалённом репозитории, а затем вывести информацию о доступных ветках другим способом

```
git fetch --all --prune
git branch --all
```